# How to get the screen size of any computer

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

So, I've looked all over the internet and I've seen a few things that state

```
window_width, window_height = pygame.display.get_surface().get_size()
```

is possible but when I do it I get an error message (window_width = pygame.display.get_surface().get_size()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_size')
I've seen it's possible here and well as other sites so why won't it work for me?

```
import pygame 
import random
window_width, window_height = pygame.display.get_surface().get_size()
black = (0,0,0)
close_program = False
fullscreen = False
white = (255,255,255)
random_position_x = random.randint(0, window_width)
random_position_y = random.randint(0, window_height)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pygame.display.Info()`:

The [docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.Info) say:

> current_h, current_w: Height and width of the current video mode, or
> of the desktop mode if called before the display.set_mode is called.
> (current_h, current_w are available since SDL 1.2.10, and pygame
> 1.8.0) They are -1 on error, or if an old SDL is being used.1.8.0)

`pygame.display.Info()` creates an Info Object with the attributes `current_h` and `current_w`. Create the Info Object before you call `display.set_mode` and then call display.set_mode with `current_h` and `current_w` from the object.

**Example 1:**

```
infoObject = pygame.display.Info()
pygame.display.set_mode((infoObject.current_w, infoObject.current_h))
```

**Example 2:**

```
width, height = pygame.display.Info().current_w, pygame.display.Info().current_h
```

Comment: it works which is great but I can divide it but I'll look around and see what i can come up with. Just when I'm done i can exit out